# return null as \N from psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to migrate some data from postgres to mysql. for that i'm doing a simple sql in postgres and load it to mysql. since format is a bit different the flag `-AF $'\t'` in `psql` makes it tab delimiter which is great.

The missing part is that `psql` return null as empty string. where in mysql it represent as `\N`.
Is there a flag that manage it? I would really like to avoid putting `ifnull` around each column in the select.

Comment: Are you building your own SQL statements to export a table as a complete `INSERT`?

Comment: something like that. I read an input and load it directly to the mysql target. NULLs are treated as empty strings for now and i'm looking to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

`psql` has a flag that controls the way null is outputted `-P 'null=\N'`